# What is the correct way to load a portable MetadataReference in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am trying to compile some code that is built against the portable .Net libraries and I am trying to determine the correct way to load the portable assemblies as `MetadataReference` objects.

For example, I can load the assemblies like this and it will work:

```
var analyzerCode = "// Some analyzer code here";
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(analyzerCode);

string assemblyName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
MetadataReference[] references = new MetadataReference[]
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Runtime.dll"),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation).Assembly.Location),
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace).Assembly.Location)
};

CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(assemblyName, new[] { syntaxTree }, references, new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
    // Check the result for errors and work with it
}
```

Obviously this is not very portable code as I am using file paths that may only work on my machine.  If I do the following:

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
```

I get the following exceptions:

> CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I believe this is because the solution running this code is a 4.6 assembly, so the `typeof(object)` is pointing to the 4.6 System.dll.

So my question is, what is the correct way to specify portable assemblies to use  as `MetadataReference` instances for a Roslyn compilation object?

Answer (score 5):

If you're compilation is referencing both the "full" framework 4.5 or 4.6, and you're also referencing portable libraries, you also need to add references to façade assemblies to bridge between them. You can find them at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6\Facades
```

Where you should replace v4.6 with whatever version of the desktop framework you're targeting. You should just loop through that directory and add a reference for all the assemblies you see in there.

Comment: I only want the compilation to reference the portable libraries, I was more looking for a way to ensure that I know the correct location for those portable libraries. Is it safe just to use %PROGRAMFILES(X86)% or %PROGRAMFILES% depending if I am running on x64/x86 ?  Or could it be in a different directory depending on how the user installed Visual Studio?

Comment: Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) rather than relying on environment variables, but otherwise the path relative to Program Files is fairly unlikely to change. That folder isn't dependent upon VS install path (and may be present even if VS isn't installed.)

Comment: The only "real" way to do this is to invoke the ResolveAssemblyReferences MSBuild task, but that's one of those things that if you knew about the subleties of that, you wouldn't be asking the question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Locate the path to the assembly and specify the portable library to be loaded. May look something like this:

```
var dotNetAssemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var references = new MetadataReference[]
    {
        MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(dotNetAssemblyPath, "MY_PORTABLE_FILE_TO_BE_LOADED"))
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following nuget packages:

https://github.com/jaredpar/basic-reference-assemblies

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49498

This repository now builds easy to use reference assembly DLLs. The README.md has a lot of details but in short using the NuPkg defined there you can create in memory compilations like so:

```
var code = @"
using System;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var tuple = (Part1: ""hello"", Part2: ""world"");
        Console.WriteLine($""{tuple.Part1} {tuple.Part2}"");
    }
}
";

var compilation = CSharpCompilation
    .Create(
        "HelloWorld.dll",
        new[] { CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code) },
        references: ReferenceAssemblies.Net50);

using var fileStream = new FileStream(@"p:\temp\helloworld.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
var emitResults = compilation.Emit(fileStream);
```